# how to concatenate items names of an order?

Tags: php, laravel

I added append to Order model and created the function getDetailsAttribute()  I want to concatenate each item name of an order like this

```
"details": "orange، apple، vegetables",
```

This is the Item table

```
----
items
-----
id
name
image
```

```
 protected $appends =['details'];


    public function getDetailsAttribute()
    {
        $items = $this->items();

        foreach ($items as $item)
        {
            $names = $item->name;
        }

        return $items;
    }
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: `$names = implode("", $item->name);`.

Comment: you want output as sting ? can you show what is single `$item` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
public function getDetailsAttribute()
    {
        $names = "details :";
        $items = $this->items();

        foreach ($items as $item)
        {
            $names += $item->name.", ";
        }

        return $names;
    }
```

Comment: $names .= $item->name.", ";

Answer (score 0):

```
 $items = $this->items();
$names= ''; // create a empty string 

    foreach ($items as $item)
    {
        $names += $item->name;
    }

    return $items;
```

That will do the job.